# How to fix, value stored to "NSMutableArray" during its initialization never read warnnig

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, warnings

I have got some warnings when analyzing objective-c app

[image]

How can i resolve this kind of warnings.

Comment: You never accept answers, so why would anyone want to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you write like this

```
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    tempDict = [self readFromPlist:kserchkeywordFileName];
```

solution :

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self readFromPlist:kserchkeywordFileName]];
```

may be this help you.
 If answer is right then accept it.